# Dynamic import of react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dynamic-import

Can we dynamically import hooks based on the value passed to the component?

For eg.

App.js

```
<BaseComponent isActive />
```

BaseComponent.js

```
if(props.isActive) {
  // import useActive (custom Hook)
}
```

I donot want these(custom hook) files to be imported and increase the size of BaseComponent even when the props contain falsey values.

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module#40277993

Comment: Here I can see isActive is always true, so there's no point of importing it conditionally,
And if the prop is not always true, so you must import useActive on the top level.

Comment: isActive is always true because it's obviously an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [dynamically import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module#40277993) hooks as it is just a function (using `require`), but **you shouldn't** because **you can't use hooks inside conditions**.

See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

> Only call Hooks **at the top level**. **Don’t call Hooks inside** loops, **conditions**, or nested functions.

If you want conditionally use a hook, use the condition in **its implementation** ([look for example at `skip` option of `useQuery` hook from Apollo GraphQL Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489097/use-query-hook-react-apollo-conditional-call/59489673#59489673)).

```
const useActive = (isUsed) => {
  if (isUsed) {
    // logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this not affect the size of the BaseComponent which did not require `useActive` at all is `props.isActive` is false?

Comment: It will add a few **bytes** to the file size, but why you even consider it? Also, you don't have any other options as you restricted to React API, Please read: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Higher Order Component that fetches the hook and then passes it down as a prop to a wrapped component. By doing so the wrapped component can use the hook without breaking the rules of hooks, eg from the wrapped component's point of view, the reference to the hook never changes and the hook gets called everytime the wrapped component renders.  Here is what the code would look like:

```
export function withDynamicHook(hookName, importFunc, Component) {
    return (props) => {
        const [hook, setHook] = useState();

        useEffect(() => {
            importFunc().then((mod) => setHook(() => mod[hookName]));
        }, []);

        if (!hook) {
            return null;
        }

        const newProps = { ...props, [hookName]: hook };
        return <Component {...newProps} />;
    };
}

// example of a Component using it:
const MyComponent = ({useMyHook}) => {
    let something = useMyHook();
    console.log(something)
    return <div>myHook returned something, see the console to inspect it </div>
}
const MyComponentWithHook = withDynamicHook('useMyHook', () => import('module-containing-usemyhook'), MyComponent)
```

Comment: This pattern is perfectly valid and there are good reasons you would want to do this. The rules are just there to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @AndreiSavin I think that is fair, I edited my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should extract the logic inside the `useActive` hook and dynamically import it instead of dynamically importing the hook since you should not **call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**., checkout [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

Let's say your `useActive` hook was trying to update the document title (in real world, it has to be a big chunk of code that you would consider using dynamic import)

It might be implemented as below:

```
// useActive.js

import { useEffect } from "react";    
export function useActive() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "(Active) Hello World!";
  }, []);
}
```

And you tried to use it in the `BaseComponent`:

```
// BaseComponent.js

function BaseComponent({ isActive }) {
  if (isActive) { // <-- call Hooks inside conditions ❌
    import("./useActive").then(({ useActive }) => {
      useActive();
    });
  }
  return <p>Base</p>;
}
```

Here you violated the rule "don't call Hooks inside conditions" and will get an `Invalid hook call.` error.

So instead of dynamically import the hook, you can extract the logic inside the hook and dynamically import it:

```
// updateTitle.js

export function updateTitle() {
  document.title = "(Active) Hello World!"
}
```

And you do the `isActive` check inside the hook:

```
// BaseComponent.js

function BaseComponent({ isActive }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isActive) return;

    import("./updateTitle").then(({ updateTitle }) => {
      updateTitle();
    });
  }, [isActive]);

  return <p>Base</p>;
}
```

It works fine without violating any rules of hooks.

I have attached a CodeSandbox for you to play around:

[image: Edit hardcore-wing-p3uvc]

Comment: It is against the rules of hooks.

Comment: In what way? This is not using hook inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Comment: *Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.*
So importing it in a regular callback and using it there will violate the above rule.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Here I am not importing the hook function but the extracted logic inside the original hook.

Comment: Either case, it is a hook being used inside the callback.

Comment: Hi Siraj, my answer might be unclear and caused some misunderstanding. I have elaborated on my explanation. Would you please have a look and let me know you thought? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215681/discussion-between-hangindev-and-siraj-alam).

Answer (score 0):

To whoever encountered it as well: You can't use Hooks inside dynamically imported components(however, apparently if you does not use hooks even the first example works):

instead of:

```
const useDynamicDemoImport = (name) => {
  const [comp, setComp] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    let resolvedComp = false;
    import(`@site/src/demos/${name}`)
      .then((m) => {
        if (!resolvedComp) {
          resolvedComp = true;
          setComp(m.default);
        }
      })
      .catch(console.error);
    return () => {
      resolvedComp = true;
    };
  }, []);
  return comp;
};

const DemoPreviewer: FC<DemoPreviewerProps> = (props) => {
  comp = useDynamicDemoImport(props.name);
  return (
    <Paper sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
      {comp}
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default DemoPreviewer
```

use React Lazy instead and render the component later

```
const useDynamicDemoImport = (name) => {
  const Comp = React.lazy(() => import(`@site/src/demos/${name}`));
  return comp;
};

const RootDemoPreviewer: FC<DemoPreviewerProps> = (props) => {
  console.log("RootDemoPreviewer");
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <DemoPreviewer {...props} />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};

const DemoPreviewer: FC<DemoPreviewerProps> = (props) => {
  const Comp = useDynamicDemoImport(props.name);
  return (
    <Paper sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <Comp />
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default RootDemoPreviewer
```